# Why browsers send get request instead of post request in my React project that uses Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a dispatch in one of my components that calls by form submission:

```
const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    dispatch(resetPassActionCreator(values.email));
  };
```

and this is `resetPassActionCreator` function:

```
export const resetPassActionCreator = username => dispatch => {
    const url = PASSWORD_RESET_GET_EMAIL;
    dispatch(
        apiCallBegan({
            url,
            method: "POST",
            onStart: passwordResetSlice.actions.resetPassword.type,
            onSuccess: passwordResetSlice.actions.resetPasswordSuccess.type,
            onError: passwordResetSlice.actions.resetPasswordFail.type,
            data: {
                username,
            },
        })
    );
};
```

and I check the `url` and it does not have '**/**' at the end.
can anyone tell me why the browser sends get request instead of post?

Comment: What's inside `apiCallBegan` ?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually sending a get request? What is it supposed to be doing, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: `apiCallBegan` is just a `createAction` function of reduxjs/toolkit.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a problem with the browser. 
Probably you are using `apiCallBegan` in the wrong way ) 
or its implementation does not support `POST` requests.